# missing 1 required positional argument: 'after'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

so i've made a private bot in only two servers and what i wanted it to do is to automatically change his profile picture whenever the server he was in changes. but when i try to trigger the command by changing the server's icon, it just says:

> File "C:\Users\AcerAspire\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python301\site-package\discord\client.py", line 343, in *run_event* await coro(*args, **kwargs), TypeError: on_guild_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'after'

and here's my code

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_update(ctx, before: discord.Guild, after: discord.Guild):
   if before.icon != after.icon:
       await bot.user.edit(avatar=ctx.guild.icon_url)
```

what is the cause? when i try to put the 'ctx' anywhere in between/after/before it says the exact same thing, and when i get it out it says it needs ctx...
what is the problem?

Comment: From the documentation, `on_guild_update` does not get a `ctx` parameter.  Just `before` and `after`.

Comment: yes but the ctx.guild.icon_url does

Comment: You don't get to just *decide* that a library function takes additional arguments. The function you're overriding has [this signature](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_guild_update), so you're expected to respect that signature. You did not write the discord.py library, so you don't get to say what it does and doesn't do.

Comment: i didn't mean it like this, what i wanted to say is that nothing other than 'ctx.guild.icon_url' works and if i don't put 'ctx' in it errors but when i do put it it thinkd the others are inexistant

Comment: The ERROR happens when the Discord software calls YOUR function, because it is passing two parameters, and your function expects three.  I don't understand why you are arguing with us.  You will need to get the icon_url from one of those two objects.

Comment: i'm not trying to argue, but just to understand and get help as i'm a beginner and i didn't understand everything, sorry if i am annoying

Answer (score 0):

As you already show in your type hints, both `before` and `after` are already `discord.Guild` objects. Instead of `ctx.guild` just use `before` to get the guild before the update, or `after` for the guild after the update. So `after.icon_url` should work fine. You already had it in the equality check.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_update(before: discord.Guild, after: discord.Guild):
   if before.icon != after.icon:
       await bot.user.edit(avatar=after.icon_url)
```

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild_update#discord.on_guild_update